# Does spring flow naming conventions for setter functions

Tags: spring

I am a newbie for springs. I tried with many combination. I came to conclusion that for spring it flow strict convention for setter function for member variables.
is there any way to customize the setter function name for a member variable.

```
public class HelloWorld {
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }

   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
}
```

Is there any specifications about this? I cannot even customize the visibility of setter  from **public ==> protected** , my finding as as this function need to access from outside from spring container.

Answer (score 2):

The specification is called [JavaBeans](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/spec-136004.html) (you might be interested in the *Introspection* chapter) and **no, you can not change the naming convention.**

If you are talking about data binding and property paths, **you HAVE TO follow the convention.**

However you can call functions within SpEL or Unified EL (depending on your use-case). So if you want just to get your custom getter value `#{myBean.fooBar()}`.